# Laravel 5.8 Undefined variable while using "With" Clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

Here is my **controller** code:

```
$exam_categories = ExamCategory::all();
return view('test.test-home')->withExamCategories($exam_categories);
```

Here is my **blade** template code:

```
<select class="custom-select form-control-lg exam-category" id="exam-category" style="font-weight: bold">
     <option selected>Select</option>
     @foreach($exam_categories as $examCategory)
          <option value="{{$examCategory->id}}">{{$examCategory->Category}}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

If I run this code then it shows the following **error**:

> Undefined variable: **exam_categories** (View: /var/www/myproj/resources/views/test/test-home.blade.php)

It was working fine in laravel 5.4 version, but when I updated to laravel 5.8, it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using compact instead.

```
 $exam_categories = ExamCategory::all();
    return view('test.test-home', compact('exam_categories'));
```

OR

```
 $exam_categories = ExamCategory::all();
    return view('test.test-home')->with(['exam_categories' => $exam_categories]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is 2 way to pass data to view:

1. ```
   $exam_categories = ExamCategory::all();
   return view('test.test-home')->with('exam_categories',$exam_categories);
   ```
2. ```
   $exam_categories = ExamCategory::all();
   return view('test.test-home',['exam_categories',$exam_categories]);
   ```

Now you can easily access a variable in a view using `$exam_categories`.

For more information, you can read documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#passing-data-to-views)